# Can Pythonista projects with GUI be made into an executable file and run on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, executable, pythonista

I have been writing little calculator programs on my iPhone that do arcane calculations, used by machinists to make fancy metal parts. I have been making GUIs, and writing the code in Pythonista on my iPhone, but I can't figure out how to make the app into .exe code. I would like to do this, to make it easy for people in the machine shop to use the code, without accidentally messing it up. Does pyinstaller work with Pythonista? Would I compile on a desktop, and then somehow move the code to the iPhone? How would I move it to the iPhone as an executable? Apple makes things so hard!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Xcode and the Xcode template. See [Xcode Template for Pythonista](https://github.com/omz/PythonistaAppTemplate) on Github, by the author of Pythonista.

The template will allow compiling your Pythonista app for iOS, and Xcode can load it onto your device for testing. At that point, the submission process is the same as for any app.